# Paid Family Leave in New York State

Tags: employment, new-york-state

If I take FMLA and use sick time and vacation time during my leave, would I still be able to receive any monies from NYS thru its Paid Family Leave? Or since I am being paid, I would not be eligible for additional remuneration.

Answer (score 1):

An employee can only choose to use paid time off during Paid Family Leave if the employer allows it. Taking paid time off at the same time as Paid Family Leave may allow the employee to receive their full salary for all or part of the leave. *However, an employee cannot receive more than their full wages while receiving Paid Family Leave benefits.*

Just had to follow lots of different links.

Leaving in case anyone else may be interested.

This was found in the *other* benefits site of NYS .gov.